# Как обработать события дочернего потока коллекции модели в MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, mvvm

У меня есть две модели вида

```
public class Model1
{
    public Int32 SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
    public event Action<Int32> SomeProperty1Changed;
}
public class Model2
{
    public Int32 SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
    public event Action<Int32> SomeProperty1Changed;
    public ObservableCollection<Model1> Models { get; private set; }
}
```

Эти модели могут редактироваться в второстепенном потоке.
Эти данные у меня должен получить мой `Control`, что бы отрисовать их на `Canvas` через code behind.
С обработкой событий простых свойств все понятно. Создаю ViewModel, который будет внутри обработчика события вызывать `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` для синхронизации.
А вот как мне быть с обработкой событий коллекции?
Либо `ViewModel` выступает просто оберткой над объектом модели, ничего с ней не делая. В этом случае мне потребуется вызывать `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` в code behind моего `Control` для синхронизации. В этом случае выходит меньше всего лишних действий, но мне почему-то не нравится эта система. Я так понимаю это нарушение MVVM, потому и не нравится мне это.
Либо `ViewModel` ловит события коллекции и делает то-же самое с своей коллекцией, но уже в потоке окна. Этот вариант мне нравится больше, но тут выходит больше лишних движений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный путь — VM должна прятать от View подробности работы модели, так что код View в принципе не должен подозревать о существовании нескольких потоков.

Если ваша VM работает с коллекцией моделей и управляет коллекцией вложенных VM, то да, ей нужно заниматься переносом событий об обновлениях в главный поток.

Если вы видите, что получается много лишнего, возможно, вам один раз стоит написать вспомогательный метод или класс, который будет заниматься этим.

```
class ObservableCollectionForwarder<S, D> : IDisposable
{
    Func<S, D> mapper;
    ObservableCollection<S> source;
    ObservableCollection<D> destination;

    Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public ObservableCollectionForwarder<S, D>(
        ObservableCollection<S> source,
        ObservableCollection<D> destination,
        Func<S, D> mapper)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        source.NotifyCollectionChanged += OnSourceChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        source.NotifyCollectionChanged -= OnSourceChanged;
    }

    void OnSourceChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => OnSourceChangedInternal(o, args));
    }

    void OnSourceChangedInternal(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            {
                var index = args.NewStartingIndex;
                foreach (var targetItem in args.Cast<S>.Select(mapper))
                    target.Insert(index++, targetItem);
                break;
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

С другой стороны, если вы посчитаете, что ваша модель должна по-другому общаться с внешним миром (например, выставить `IObservable`), это ничего не поменяет в UI, поменяется только обвязка.

```
class RxForwarder<S, D> : IDisposable
{
    Func<S, D> mapper;
    IObservable<S> source;
    ObservableCollection<D> destination;
    IDisposable subscription;

    public ObservableCollectionForwarder<S, D>(
        IObservable<S> source,
        ObservableCollection<D> destination,
        Func<S, D> mapper)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.subscription = source
               .ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
               .Subscribe(OnNewItem);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription.Dispose;
    }

    void OnNewItem(S item)
    {
        target.Add(item);
    }
}
```